# FastApi ошибка No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' при длительных запросах

Tags: python, cors, fastapi

Для доступа API из фронта использую **ngrok.exe http 80**. При запросах с фронтеда в API выполняется фильтрация данных которая длится 10min+, но проблема в том, что на фронте получаю ошибку спустя 5 минут....

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://0c79-37-112-0-90.eu.ngrok.io/integration/start_filter' from origin 'Тут был урл фронта' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

У бекенда вроде бы корсы настроены так как должны.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

from .routers.router import router

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)



app.include_router(router)
```

Вопрос в том, ошибка из-за бекенда или ngrok и можно ли её пофиксить? Выполнял запросы с фронта, requests и postman везде одно и тоже, только ошибки трактовались по разному

Comment: Возможно где-то (на фронте?) таймаут по умолчанию стоит 600 секунд?

Comment: В принципе можно попробовать переделать логику, чтобы запрос не висел, пока формируется ответ, а ставился на обработку, а потом следующими запросами проверялся статус - готово или нет.

Comment: @insolor на фронте таймаут вообще убран